# Laravel - storage_path function doubles path

Tags: laravel, path, laravel-9, laravel-filesystem

I'm trying to get a path to a file in my storage folder. Although the `storage_path()` function duplicates the given path.

My code

```php
$firstFile = 'app/public/temp/' . $timestamp . '/' . $tempName . '1.pdf';
$secondFile = 'app/public/temp/' . $timestamp . '/' . $tempName . '2.pdf';
$path1 = storage_path($firstFile);
$path2 = storage_path($secondFile);
dd($path1, $path2);
```

My result:

```
"/var/www/html/storage/app/public/temp/public/temp/1678441063/tempName1.pdf/public/temp/1678441063/tempName2.pdf1.pdf"
"/var/www/html/storage/app/public/temp/public/temp/1678441063/tempName1.pdf/public/temp/1678441063/tempName2.pdf2.pdf"
```

Wanted result:

```
"/var/www/html/storage/app/public/temp/1678441063/tempName1.pdf"
"/var/www/html/storage/app/public/temp/1678441063/tempName2.pdf"
```

My `filesystem.php` (file shortened for only relevant code)

```php
<?php

return [
    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'local'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],

];
```

I have tried removing `app/public` from `$firstFile` but that leaves me with the same result.

I also ran the `php artisan storage:link` command.

I use `php 8.1` and `Laravel 9.19`

Comment: Try dd ($timestamp, $tempName). I am affraid of that there is something wrong with these variables

Comment: @KhangTran Thanks, you were right. I passed the wrong variables instead of the $timestamp and $tempname to the function in which my code is. Such a silly mistake by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed thanks to @KhangTran's comment.

My `$timestamp` and `$tempName` contained a path instead of what they should contain.